# how to make text ellipsis in second line in ie 9

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-9

I want to limit text with the container, I have to make **text ellipsis in second line**. **I want this work in ie9**. Charter should be limited with ... either css or jquery can be applied. But it have re-sizable width, depending upon the width resizing text should be limited with in the wrapper. left and right of text have some images so the position absolute cant be removed. it affect all the styles. Example  code below. Please refer it. I cant add any jquery plugin for it. only pure jquery or javascript or css can be applied

```css
.container{
            width:450px;
            margin:0 auto;
        }
        .myText{
            position: absolute;
            top: 10px;
            left: 60px;
            margin-right: 24px;
            height: 100%;
            word-break: break-word;
        }
        .myText-Wrap{
            background: #e8e5e5;
            min-height: 40px;
            margin-top: 2px;
            font-size: 13px;
            cursor: pointer;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
        }
        .mytag{
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
            display: block;
            min-height: 40px;
            float: left;
            overflow: hidden;
            text-overflow: ellipsis;
            word-break: break-all;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="myText-Wrap">
            <a href="#" class="mytag"> <span class="myText">jfgsdjjjjjjjjjj sdhfgsdhf shdfgashdfs hasgfashfa ahsgfhasgfhas ashgfhasgfhasf hasgfahsfasf asghfahsfga ajsfgashgfs f jasgfagsf</span> </a>
        </div>
        <div class="myText-Wrap">
            <a href="#" class="mytag"> <span class="myText">jfgsdjjjjjjjjjj sdhfgsdhf shdfgashdfs hasgfashfa ahsgfhasgfhas ashgfhasgfhasf hasgfahsfasf asghfahsfga ajsfgashgfs f jasgfagsf</span> </a>
        </div>
        <div class="myText-Wrap">
            <a href="#" class="mytag"> <span class="myText">jfgsdjjjjjjjjjj sdhfgsdhf shdfgashdfs hasgfashfa ahsgfhasgfhas ashgfhasgfhasf hasgfahsfasf asghfahsfga ajsfgashgfs f jasgfagsf</span> </a>
        </div>
        <div class="myText-Wrap">
            <a href="#" class="mytag"> <span class="myText">j122 ajsajjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj jhjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj</span> </a>
        </div>
        <div class="myText-Wrap">
            <a href="#" class="mytag"> <span class="myText">xzxzx</span> </a>
        </div>
        <div class="myText-Wrap">
            <a href="#" class="mytag"> <span class="myText">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</span> </a>
        </div>
        <div class="myText-Wrap">
            <a href="#" class="mytag"> <span class="myText">jfgsdjjjjjjjjjj sdhfgsdhf shdfxcvbx fhasgfhas ashgfhasgfhasf hasgfahsfasf asghfahsfga ajsfgashgfs f jasgfagsf</span> </a>
        </div>
        <div class="myText-Wrap">
            <a href="#" class="mytag"> <span class="myText">jfgsdjjjjjjjjjj sdhfgsdhf f jasgfagsf</span> </a>
        </div>
        <div class="myText-Wrap">
            <a href="#" class="mytag"> <span class="myText">jfgsdjjjjjjjjjj sdhfgsdhf shdfgashdfs hasgfashfa ahsgfhasgfhas ashgfhasgfhasf hasgfahsfasf asghfahsfga ajsfgashgfs f jasgfagsf</span> </a>
        </div>
        <div class="myText-Wrap">
            <a href="#" class="mytag"> <span class="myText">jfgsdjjjjjjjjjj sdhfgsdhffhasf hasgfahsfasf asghfahsfga ajsfgashgfs f jasgfagsf</span> </a>
        </div>
        <div class="myText-Wrap">
            <a href="#" class="mytag"> <span class="myText">jfgsdjjjjjjjjjj sdhfgsdhf f jasgfagsf</span> </a>
        </div>
        <div class="myText-Wrap">
            <a href="#" class="mytag"> <span class="myText">jfgsdjjjjjjjjjj</span> </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Please help ...